# How do I make a type that is convertible from all other types using From<T>?

Tags: rust

I want my type `MyError` to be convertible from all other types. I tried doing this as follows:

```rust
impl<T> From<T> for MyError {
    fn from(_: T) -> Self {
        MyError::Unknown
    }
}
```

But I receive the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<MyError>` for type `MyError`
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 |     impl<T> From<T> for MyError {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

This makes sense because one such `T` is necessarily `MyError`, and this implementation is covered by `impl<T> From<T> for T`. Ideally, I would be able to exclude `MyError` from `T` like:

```rust
impl<T> From<T> for MyError where T != MyError
```

but obviously this doesn't work. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you can't do that cause of blanked implementation.

Comment: You can't do this, so maybe give us some more information on why you are trying to do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given exactly what you specified you can achieve it using the `auto_traits` and `negative_impls` nightly-only features as follows:

```rust
#![feature(auto_traits, negative_impls)]

enum MyError {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    Unknown,
}


auto trait IsNotMyError {}

impl !IsNotMyError for MyError {}


impl<T: IsNotMyError> From<T> for MyError {
    fn from(_: T) -> Self {
        Self::Unknown
    }
}
```

However, this impl isn't very useful for `?`, which is what I assume you're using it for.

Assuming you receive a `Result<T, E>` and want to convert `E` to `MyError::Unknown` using `?`, it won't work:

```rust
fn f<T, E>(f: impl FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>) -> Result<T, MyError> {
    let value = f()?;
    
    Ok(value)
}
```

You'll receive the following error message:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `E: IsNotMyError` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:24:20
    |
24  |     let value = f()?;
    |                    ^ the trait `IsNotMyError` is not implemented for `E`
```

This is because `E` could be `MyError` and then it's unclear whether the return error should just be `E` or `MyError::Unknown`.

It's instead advised to just do `.map_err(|_| MyError::Unknown)?` if you want to discard the error, as opposed to implementing `From<T>` for it:

```rust
fn f<T, E>(f: impl FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>) -> Result<T, MyError> {
    let value = f().map_err(|_| MyError::Unknown)?;
    
    Ok(value)
}
```

That is, assuming you want to discard the original error, else simply wrap your error enum with a generic `E` and pass the error back.

You can find more information about the features above in the [unstable book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/):

- [`auto_traits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/auto-traits.html)
- [`negative_impls`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html)

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation, thanks!

Comment: I would appreciated source link to learn more about these feature.

Comment: @Stargateur You can find more information about them in the [unstable book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/): [Auto traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/auto-traits.html) and [Negative impls](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html)

Comment: my bad, I mean *in* the answer, comment fly away